# Autorelease pool crashing App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autorelease

My autorelease pool is crashing my app at random, what is the common cause of this problem?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0145ba63 objc_msgSend + 23
1   CoreFoundation                  0x01210a6c CFRelease + 92
2   CoreFoundation                  0x012f2e8a -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 170
3   CoreFoundation                  0x01210a6c CFRelease + 92
4   CoreFoundation                  0x01235b8d _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 237
5   Foundation                      0x0005886c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 559
6   CoreFoundation                  0x012dafe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
7   CoreFoundation                  0x012dc594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
8   CoreFoundation                  0x01238cc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
9   CoreFoundation                  0x01238240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
10  CoreFoundation                  0x01238161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
11  GraphicsServices                0x01c2e268 GSEventRunModal + 217
12  GraphicsServices                0x01c2e32d GSEventRun + 115
13  UIKit                           0x002e842e UIApplicationMain + 1160
14  FancyAPint                      0x000029e8 main + 102 (main.m:14)
15  FancyAPint                      0x00002979 start + 53
```

I know this is because an object is being over released, am i correct in thinking an object is being released before the autorelease pool is trying to release it. Therefore the autorelease pool attempts to over release an object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your assessment is correct. Try running your app using the "Zombies" instrument in the simulator, or setting the NSZombieEnabled environmental variable to YES. These will both give you more information about what objects are being overreleased.

Comment: Using a combination of NSZombie and checking the crash logs i was able to locate the problem, an object being released in a classes dealloc which was released in the auto release pool.

Answer (score 0):

This will be because of extra memory releases. Do not release the object which is being allocated inside auto-release pool and is inited from object which has its own memory. This may the one reason behind this as i also faced this problem.